# MySql 5.6 Dynamically Partition Table based on user defined date

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a basic mysql function that I can call nightly in order to partition a table into two partitions, one which contains everything before a given date, and the other containing everything after a given date. I have the following, but I keep getting this error. Is there a way I can use a passed in date in order to partition this table?

`1064. Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed near '),    PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));  END' at line 7`

```
DELIMITER $
$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UpdateEventsPartitions $$
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEventsPartitions (IN `@PartitionDate` datetime)
BEGIN
    DECLARE toDays int;
    SET toDays = TO_DAYS(@PartitionDate);

     ALTER TABLE events REORGANIZE PARTITION p01,p02 INTO (
        PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN (toDays),
        PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the best way but I was able to solve my issue with this.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UpdateEventsPartitions $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_events_partitions (IN `@PartitionDate` datetime)
BEGIN
     SET @sql := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE events REORGANIZE PARTITION p01,p02 INTO ('
                        ,'PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('
                        , CAST((`@PartitionDate`+0) as char(8))
                        ,')),'
                        ,'PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));');

     Select @sql as sqlStatement;
     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```